# Sencha touch 2: Getting error 'Object has no method 'getControllrer' while creating the production build

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am working on a sencha touch 2.1.0. I have created production build using sencha cmd 3.0.The production build is successful but While running the application (production build) , I am getting following error

**Error evaluating http://xx.xx.xx.xxx/DH/DH_Prod/production/app.js with message: TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getController'.**

I am working with 2 controllers in my application and both are working fine until I created the productionBuild.

Comment: Could you please post your `app.json`?

Comment: {"id":"6fffd3cd-017c-47f1-b922-91ad4b03cf00","js":[{"path":"app.js","bundle":true,"update":"delta","type":"js",
"version":"ff75b16417cac609010e5b4584daa45edce1ccd1"}],"css":[{"path":"resources/css/app.css","update":"delta","type":"css",
"version":"f430d55d41ca4dcbd67681a0012bca814c2420bf"}]}

Comment: my app.json is as above. Thank you

Comment: Thanks rdougan. I got the solution and posted it as below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the actual solution as below.

There were places where I was directly accessing the controller such as this.MYapp.getController('MyController') and not as  this.getApplication().getController('MyController') which was causing the issue during the production build but not in development version.